# Is VTD-XML Reliable and open source?

Tags: java

We are developing the application by uploading the file and validating through xml file by using xpath query.We were using JAVA DOM Parser but now due to memory problem we have selected VTD-XML because it is supporting xpath expression than sax or stax.I have couple of doubt
    1. Is VTD-XML is reliable.
    2. Is it open source.
    can you suggest whether i can go with VTD-XML or not?

```
Regards,
Tharanya B
```

Comment: If it is reliable is strictly opinion-based. If it's open-source - source code is available under GPLv2 (https://sourceforge.net/projects/vtd-xml/). Make sure you are aware of implications of GPL licenses.

Comment: Thanks for your response sir.I have checked in above mentioned link.vtd-xml is available there.vtd-xml is open source right can I proceed with vtd-xml?